# Three.js not showing my texture

Tags: image, textures, webgl, three.js

I need to make a ball with a texture on it. I'm very new at WebGL and Three.js. The problem is that I see a White Sphere but not the texture on it. As a new user I am not able to submit a picture.

The code part is this:

```
function init() {

            canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' ); 


            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;



            scene = new THREE.Scene();

                            camera.lookAt (scene.position); 


                            var llum = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
                            llum.intensity=50;


                            llum.position.x=camera.position.x;
                            llum.position.y=camera.position.y;
                            llum.position.z=camera.position.z;

                            llum.lookAt(scene.position);

                            scene.add(llum);



                            var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('ull.jpg');


            texture.needsUpdate = true;

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( texture );

            var quality = 16, step = 1024 / quality;

            var geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(500,100,100);



            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geom, material );


            scene.add( mesh );


            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true});
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            canvas.innerHTML = ""; 

                            //Afegim al canvas el que hem de renderitzar
            canvas.appendChild( renderer.domElement );



            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );


            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the first page that shows up in Google search results I will post what was solution in my case. I draw texture on square but the square was actually rotated backward so camera saw back of the square without texture, after fixing rotation everything worked fine.

```
   var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(FLOOR_SIZE, FLOOR_SIZE, 10, 10);

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load('images/floor.jpg', function ( texture ) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: texture, 
            overdraw: 0.5
        });

        var floor = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

        // ROTATION THAT MADE SQUARE INVISIBLE WAS Math.PI/2

        floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
        floor.position.y = -0.1;
        scene.add(floor);
     });
```